# useMemo not preventing component rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Button component that's being used as a child for a Timer component. Depending on whether the Timer is active or not, this determines the Button's kind (either pause or start).

```
<Button
  kind={ buttonType }
  handleClick={() => toggleTimer()}
/>
```

The Button component will rerender every time the Timer component is rerendering after every second, which isn't necessary. After reading [this article by Kent Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback), it seems like a small unnecessarily rerendering component like this is probably insignificant, but I wanted to try memoizing the component anyway to prevent it from rerendering.

I've been using React Dev Tools to highlight rerenders for the components. This is what it looks like when the Timer component and the child Buttons rerender at the same time. The buttons should not rerender every second, but only when the buttonType changes:

[image]

I tried using `useMemo` and `useCallback` to prevent these rerenders by passing memoized versions of these props to the Button component.

```
const memoizedKind = useMemo(() => buttonType, [buttonType]);
const memoizedHandleClick = useCallback(() => toggleTimer(), [buttonType]);

...

<Button
  kind={memoizedKind}
  handleClick={memoizedHandleClick}
/>
```

While this doesn't seem to break anything, the Button component still seems to rerender, and the green highlight still occurs every second for the memoized Button.

Comment: Please make a full producible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), uploading to codesanbox can do the work

Comment: Just to be sure, is your `Button` component wrapped into the `memo` HOC  `memo(Button)`?

Comment: It's not wrapped in the HOC memo. I've been trying to do this with useMemo instead

Comment: Even with useMemo from the parent, you should use memo HOC to prevent a re-rendering, otherwise even if the props are not changed, Button will be re-render if tis parent is. Using memo HOC allows you to prevent re-rendering if props and states don't change. useMemo and useCallback in the parent prevent props in the children to not change thanks to data memoization, but you should use both of them, memo and useMemo/Callback

Comment: Thanks @AntonioGiordano , I will give this a try and report back. I guess my line of thinking on hooks was that they were a replacement for the class-based API, but I'm probably thinking about this in the wrong way. I thought this about `createContext` and `useContext` as well, and realized later that they are not the same and should be used differently.

Comment: @AntonioGiordano `React.memo` is preventing render of child buttons. Thanks again. I'll have to look into the difference between `memo` and `useMemo`.